# How to Export Test Cases from QC 12?

Tags: hp-quality-center

I am trying to export test cases from our testing tool to QC 12.20. But I couldn't find online documentation over creating new or custom test types in QC 12.20. Our tool worked fine with QC 11. Is there any difference between 11 and 12 over custom test types or they have changed the mechanism. If so, then please direct me on how to create test types in QC 12 or 12.20